# SyntaxError thrown in if statement with multiple boolean operators

Tags: python, python-2.7, if-statement

This is my code:

```
if mode not "w" or mode not "r+":
    # do stuff
```

This results in the following error:

`SyntaxError: invalid syntax`

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`not` is not a comparison operator; it is a *unary* boolean operator, which means it only takes *one* argument.

Perhaps you wanted `!=`, not equals?

```
if mode != "w" and mode != "r+":
```

I also replaced `or` with `and`, because if the mode is equal to `'w'` it'll *also* not be equal to `'r+'`. All those negatives make it hard enough to grok, you could use:

```
if not (mode == 'w' or mode == 'r+'):
```

if that's easier to understand, logically speaking.

You can also combine the test into one by using a tuple and a negative membership test, `not in`:

```
if mode not in ('w', 'r+'):
```

which is a lot easier to read and understand.

Comment: It will, see my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
if not mode == "w" or not mode == "r+":
    ...
```

This should prevent you from seeing the `SyntaxError`. However, as these are common values for opening `file` objects to be writable, you could also try writing to the file and catch the `IOError`. Something like this,

```
f = open('blah', 'r')
try:
    f.write("Something amazing")
except IOError:
    # do something to read-only file
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't compare items with this syntax:

```
a not b
```

You need to compare them with this syntax:

```
a != b
```

So rewrite your if-statement to this:

```
if mode != "w" or mode != "r+":
    # do stuff
```

Now, having said that, that is purely syntax-based changes.

The problem is, this if-statement doesn't make sense, so even if you do the above change, it will certainly not do what you want it to do.

Consider this: What if mode is `"w"`? Then it will not be `"r+"`, and vice versa. In other words, *every* value will be different from both, or at least one of them.

I suspect you need `and` instead of `or`:

```
if mode != "w" and mode != "r+":
    # do stuff
```